# Difference between Code with Curly Braces and One without

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

When I use curly braces with the javascript some funcion, I get an unexpected result. I was looking to see if someone could help me understand what is going on?

```
const ages = [3, 10, 18, 20]
let x
x = ages.some( (a) => a===18)  // x is true
x = ages.some( (a) => {a===18})  // x is false
```

Wondering why x results to false when I add curly braces. Could someone help explain?

Comment: No curly braces = automatically returns result, Curly braces = explicitly requiring `return` statement. So in your example with the curly braces, you return undefined every time... because you need to explicitly write `return`

Answer (score 1):

Arrow function have something called implicit returns.

So if you write an expression as the body of the arrow function, it will automatically return the result.

So for `x = ages.some( (a) => a===18)`, the check `a === 18` is returned automatically as the result. The same way as if you had written `x = ages.some( (a) => { return a === 18; })`.

For the version with brackets, you don't add a return value, so it always returns undefined, even if a equals 18. You'd need to return explicitly for it to work as shown above.

Array.some() function returns `true` if at least one element returns `true` for the callback. So written without the brackets, you return true for the 3rd array element and false for the others, resulting in `true` for variable `x`.

In the version with brackets, you always return `undefined` since the function does not return anything. Undefined gets cast to false for all the values and hence, the end result is that variable `x` is also false.

Answer (score 0):

Without curly braces, your function body is limited to a single expression and the return value automatically becomes the result of that expression.

But with `{` `}` the function behaves like any other block of code: It does not implicitly return a value (i.e. it evaluates to `undefined`) unless you use an explicit `return` statement.

`(x) => x + 1` is equivalent to `(x) => { return x + 1; }`.

Comment: I really doubt this question needed an answer, and is probably a duplicate of something.

Comment: @kemicofa Find me a convincing duplicate and I'll vote for it.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using curly braces you must return the result, else it return undefined, meaning `{a===18}` will always be considered as false.
You should write

```
x = ages.some( (a) => {return a===18})
```

Answer (score 0):

`=>` without curly braces it return `a===18` boolean value

but in second case u need to return that value like `x = ages.some( (a) => {return a===18})`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good example of the different ways functions can be written in JS, and how they work.  Basically though keep in mind that the arrow functions *without* the curly braces are just shorthand for `return`.

`() => { return 'foo'; }` is identical to `() => 'foo';`

```js
//regular function with no return value
var a = 'bar';
const myFunc1 = function() { a = 'foo'; }
console.log(myFunc1(), a);

//regular function with a return value
a = 'bar';
const myFunc2 = function() { return a = 'foo'; }
console.log(myFunc2(), a);

//arrow function with a return value
a = 'bar';
const myFunc3 = () => { return b = 'foo'; }
console.log(myFunc3(), a);

//arrow function with no return value
a = 'bar';
const myFunc4 = () => { b = 'foo'; }
console.log(myFunc4(), a);

//arrow function using shorthand, which has an implicit return value
a = 'bar';
const myFunc5 = () => b = 'foo';
console.log(myFunc5(), a);
```